# Convert string to Javascript object for use in jqTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jqtree

I'm trying to use jqTree to render a collapsible tree to display data from a MySQL database via an ASP.NET project using AJAX.

**The Problem:**

I can successfully get the string containing the jqTree formatted data (which is ***not*** JSON even though they say it supports it) back from my AJAX call.  However, once I get it there it get rendered as a vertical string of characters.  If I do a typeof call on the data, it says it's a string, even though it 'looks' like an object when visually inspected via console.log.

I have tried a number of different ways to get the string into an object, with varying results.

I'm using this in the code behind to return the manufactured string:

```
return sb.ToString();
```

The resultant string looks like this (notice no wrapping quotation marks):

```
[{label: 'PCBID: 350',children:[{label: 'TimeStamp: 04-Sep-14 10:30:23'},{label: 'User:     DAVEG'},{label: 'PCBID: 350'},{label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411'},{label: 'PCB Drawing: 10348'},{label: 'Vendor: SBE'},{label: 'PO Number: 98019'}]},{label: 'Serial Number: Not Assigned'},{label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411'},{label: 'Last Test Result: None Found'}]
```

Which gets rendered like this in my div:

```
[
{
l
a
b
e
l
:

'
P
C
B
I
D
...and so on...
```

I know these are being rendered by jqTree because I can drag & drop them, they highlight when clicked on, etc., but instead of a tree view, I get a "dangling vine" view, not exactly useful.

If I simply take that same exact same string and declare it as a var inside the JS (not using the return value of message.d):

```
var data = [{label: 'PCBID: 350',children:[{label: 'TimeStamp: 04-Sep-14 10:30:23'},{label: 'User: DAVEG'},{label: 'PCBID: 350'},{label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411'},{label: 'PCB Drawing: 10348'},{label: 'Vendor: SBE'},{label: 'PO Number: 98019'}]},{label: 'Serial Number: Not Assigned'},{label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411'},{label: 'Last Test Result: None Found'}]
```

inside my JS code & use that, it displays perfectly and typeof thinks it's an object.

**Working Example so you can see what I'm looking for:**

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/yzoj9fut/)

**The Code on the JS side:**

Here's the Success portion of my AJAX call with a bunch of commented out versions that don't work either:

```
    success: function (message)
    {
        console.log("SUCCESS:  Inside processEvent AJAX success call");
        console.log(message.d);
        console.log(typeof message);
        console.log(typeof message.d);
        var data = message.d;
        //this method works, but not very useful as it's hard coded:
        //var data = [{ label: 'PCBID: 350', children: [{ label: 'TimeStamp: 04-Sep-14 10:30:23' }, { label: 'User: DAVEG' }, { label: 'PCBID: 350' }, { label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411' }, { label: 'PCB Drawing: 10348' }, { label: 'Vendor: SBE' }, { label: 'PO Number: 98019' }] }, { label: 'Serial Number: Not Assigned' }, { label: 'Assembly Drawing: 41411' }, { label: 'Last Test Result: None Found' }];
        var data = $.getJSON(message.d);
        //var data = { JSON.parse(message.d) };
        //var data = ({}).valueOf.call($.parseJSON(message.d));
        //var data = object.create(message.d);
        console.log(typeof data);
        console.log(data);
        $(function ()
        {
            $('#tree1').tree({
                data: data,
                autoOpen: false,
                saveState: true,
                dragAndDrop: true
            });
        });
```

**The Question:**

So after all that, my question is, how do I take the string from the AJAX message.d and turn it into an object so that jqTree can use it to render the tree I'm looking for?

**Working Code:**

I've added back in some of the success user informing stuff (jGrowl) so don't let that throw you.  The bit of code that fixed it is here:  `data = eval($.parseJSON(message.d));`

```
    success: function (message)
    {
        console.log("SUCCESS:  Inside processEvent AJAX success call");
        console.log(message.d);
        //if it's a non query event, do this
        if (DTO.eventData.eventType != "PCBID_query")
        {
            $.jGrowl("\nSuccessfully inserted a " + DTO.eventData.eventType + " event into the MySQL database.",
                { header: 'SUCCESS', theme: "pcb-success", life: 10000 });
        }
        //if processData was used for a PCBID query, process this code
        if (DTO.eventData.eventType === "PCBID_query")
        {
            var data = {};
            data = eval($.parseJSON(message.d));
            $(function ()
            {
                //force reload of tree data
                $('#tree1').tree('loadData', data);
                $('#tree1').tree({
                    data: data,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    saveState: true,
                    dragAndDrop: true
                });
            });
        }
```

I know the `eval` is evil & presents a security hole, however, this is all internal code that'll only be used on local servers & production floor computers so I think the risk is acceptable (as does my manager).

Comment: `eval(data)` would work in this case, but it is a security issue.  Your best solution would be to look for a real way to export JSON from your ASP.NET.  Without knowing your code, a little googling shows there are solutions out there.

Comment: I've tried exporting the data as JSON using `return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sb.ToString(), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);` but I end up with the same results when I parse it on the JS side.  This won't be used externally by anyone, so the security issue is probably moot.  I'll give you suggestion a try (although I've tried a couple of other methods using eval, just didn't include them in the examples).

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Is there another way to do this that doesn't use `eval`?  In any case since it's an internal only tool, I'm not overly worried about the security problem.  If you want to write up a quick answer I'll select it.  BTW, I saw your original answer before you deleted it using getJSON & tried it as well, didn't work.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, because you are correct that it isn't valid JSON.  All json object keys need to be `"` double quoted, which is the biggest issue with your current data.

Comment: I wonder if the jqTree object could be JSON-ified (with double quotes & such) so that it'd be able to be passed as directly?  I took their examples & dropped them on JSONLint & they didn't validate, but they did work for what I needed.  The rest of my server side stuff all works with real JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval(data)` would work in this case, but using `eval()` is usually a security issue, especially when getting data from public areas, such as user submitted SQL data.

The best solution would be to look for a real way to export JSON from your ASP.NET. Without knowing your code, a little googling shows there are solutions out there.

Comment: Security shouldn't be an issue this is an internal only tool.  Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.